# How can I Mathematically Calculate the Luminosity of a Post-Main-Sequence Star from Mass and Age?

Tags: star, stellar-evolution, mathematics

So, I saw [this question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32771/is-there-a-way-to-factor-age-into-the-mass-luminosity-relationship-for-stars) (which is quite old) and that's all well and good, but what if I need to (***very***) roughly calculate the luminosity of a star from the end of the main sequence? Let's assume that this is a non-extreme mass star (K-A) and can use $10M^{-2.5}$
To calculate (roughly) when the star will exit the main sequence. Would there be a way to include the expansion into a red giant? What about simulating the planetary nebula? Simplify as much as is needed.

Comment: Now that there's an answer posted to address all aspects of this question, I don't think closing and preventing answer posts is necessary or even productive. *voting to leave open*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rough reaction for stars between 0.5 and 2.5 solar masses:
We first need to know the initial(ZAMS) luminosity, the luminosity at the end of the main sequence(TAMS) and the MS lifetime:
$$L_\text{ZAMS}=0.7×M^4$$

$$L_\text{TAMS}=3×L_\text{ZAMS}$$

$$T=9×M^{-2.6}\text{ (in Gyr)}$$

Reg giant stage: luminosity exponentially increases from the TAMS luminosity to about 3500×solar luminosity(at the tip of RGB) lasts about 10% of main sequence

Helium burning:luminosity exponentially increases from 50 to 150×solar luminosity, lasts about 100 Myr

AGB: luminosity increases exponentially from 150×solar luminosity to 10000×mass of star(in solar masses)×solar luminosity, lasts 20 Myr

Planetary nebula: roughly constant luminosity at 10000×mass of star(in solar masses)×solar luminosity, lasts roughly 30000yr

For other mass ranges it gets much more complicated.

Calculations:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/l2nelshpnx

Comment: Ive updated the formatting.  In English don't use a dot to separate thousands, because the dot is used as a decimal point  (ie 10.001 = 10001/1000, not ten thousand and one)  What is the meaning of "L" and "M" in 150L to 10000M×solar luminosity?

Comment: I edited the my answer for clarity